# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation) error when attempting to navigate

Tags: react-native

here is the code that is causing the issue

```
<ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
    <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("ACompose")}
    >
        <View
            style={{
                top: 1,
                width: 300,
                height: 50,
                borderRadius: 20,
                backgroundColor: 'white',
                alignSelf: "center",
                borderWidth: 5,
                borderColor: 'rgb(14,59,88)',
            }}>
            <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: 20, letterSpacing: 0, alignSelf: "center", top: 6, left: -15 }}>
                New Announcement
            </Text>
            <Image
                style={{ width: 30, height: 30, left: 222, bottom: 20 }}
                source={
                    require('../assets/PLUS.png')
                }>
            </Image>
        </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
</ScrollView>
```

I am new to JS and react native so if Im doing anything wrong let me know

Answer (score 0):

You should try `optional chaining` if your preset supports it:

```
<TouchableHighlight
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("ACompose")}>
```

Otherwise, you need to check step by step:

```
<TouchableHighlight
          onPress={() => this.props && this.props.navigation && this.props.navigation.navigate && this.props.navigation.navigate("ACompose")}>
```